# How can I rerun validation on a saved model in Keras

Tags: validation, neural-network, keras

I have a Keras neural network and am using the `checkpoint` callback to save the model whenever it beats its prior validation score.

I can load the model back in easily enough using

```
model = keras.models.load_model("savedcheckpointfilename.h5")
```

I then want to extract the `loss` and `val_loss` values from the last epoch before the model was saved.

How can I do this?

I have tried running another epoch of training, but this will, I presume, change the weights. I don't know exactly what validation set was used, as Keras automates this during training, hence don't see how I can run explicit predictions vs the validation data (as which part of the training set was reserved for validation is not exposed AFAICS).

Comment: From a bit of digging, it looks like I can save the history returned from the fit function to at least see the history, but I'd still like to be able to reevaluate the validation. It looks like the history object also stored the validation data in the validation field, but it's not clear how to pass this into prediction/evaluation.

Comment: I don't know what the validation data is; I pass a training set and a validation_split (0.1) into the fit() function of Keras. In theory I could just pass in my own validation_data using the validation_data parameter of fit, but there's a bug on windows where this doesn't work, hence using validation_data instead of validation_split isn't a viable workaround for me. I'll try to dig out the reference for the bug, Either way it's a legit question how to reevaluate the validation loss when using the validation_split approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras seems to take **the last part of the data as the validation split.**

So if you manually split your training data with the exact same value that you defined in `model.fit(... validation_split= <your ratio here>)` you can get your validation data anytime later and do a simple `model.evaluate()` with that.

I just verified with the [Pima Indians Example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/evaluate-performance-deep-learning-models-keras/) and it works:

> **Training**: Epoch 1/1
>   250/250 - 0s - loss: val_loss: 0.6712 - val_acc: 0.6560
>
> **Model evaluate done with manual split** - ETA: 0s _ loss: 0.6712% _ acc: 0.6560%

The split point needs to be rounded up if not on an integer boundary.

```
def checkValScore(modelFile, X_train, Y_train, split=0.1) :

    model = keras.models.load_model(modelFile)
    split =  -int(math.ceil(X_train.shape[0]* split))
    X_cv = np.array(X_train)[split:]
    Y_cv = np.array(Y_train)[split:]
    return model.evaluate(X_cv, Y_cv)
```

Comment: Thanks! -This works with the minor caveat that you need to round the validation set fraction up if it's not on an integer boundary. I've editted your answer to reflect that, if you're ok I'll then mark it good.

Comment: @TomWalker Great. Glad you could solve it! And sure: Thanks for the edit, that's fine.